# cpanel access files from server IP address

Tags: cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

My domain is expired. How can I access files from IP address?
I tried this url:
http://31.220.105.186/~shopn780/public_html/index.html

Where 31.220.105.186 is IP address, shopn780 is my username...
2-3 years ago I can do it like this. But now, I couldn't. 
Is my url wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should usually look like this:

http://31.220.105.186/~shopn780/index.html

As the temporary URL is by default linked to your public_html folder and you do not need to type it.

Still in your case your hosting provider has disabled this. Most do it for security reasons.

If you have root WHM access,  you can enable it from the Apache mod_userdir tweak option :

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Apache+mod_userdir+Tweak

If you don't have root access,  you will need to contact your hosting provider and ask them to enable it for you.

As an alternative solution,  you can also use your computer hosts file (in case they don't want to enable it).